# Release UIViewController give exception

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have UIViewController that i add to the UIViewControler with this:

```
ReportViewController *reportVC = [[ReportViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ReportViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:reportVC.view];
```

And i try to add

```
[reportVC release];
```

after this lines and i get exepction when i try to remove this reportVC.view with

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Did i make a error while release it like this?

Comment: How about posting the exception?

Comment: Use ARC in your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are removing "self.view" from superview, which you shouldn't. 
You have to remove "reportVC.view" from superview.

You can write like this:

```
[reportVC.view removeFromSuperView];

[reportVC release];

reportVC = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will need your class instance later in your code then don't release it. You need to declare it in your .h file and call `[reportVC release]` in your `- (void) dealloc` method.

Answer (score 0):

Self in that context would be the memory that you released when you called [reportVC release].  Then you are accessing a property "self.view" on an object that was released.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [reportVC release]
```

It means u released the memory of viewcontroller object.Again u r trying to do operation with viewcontroller object which is already released.So remove that statement at there and write in dealloc method or use arc project where there is no need of releasing memory by u.It automatically release.